# Вызов нескольких функций класса разом

Tags: php

Сразу извиняюсь если некорректно назвал топик, но интересует такая тема:

```
class my_class{
}
$test = new my_class();
$test->func1()->func2()->....->funcN();
```

Интересует момент, можно (*и если можно, то как*) реализовать такой момент:

```
$test->func1()->func2()->....->funcN();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение, называется `Fluent Interface`

```
   class my_class{
        public function funcA()
        {
            return $this;
        }
        public function funcB()
        {
            return 'Вызов N2';
        }

    }

$t = new my_class();
echo $t->funcA()->funcB();
```

Answer (score 4):

Да можно, для таких вызовов функции должны возвращать указатель на инстанс класса ($this)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/188846)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin является ответом. [Содержательный ответ удалён как «В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5703)

Comment: @0xdef не стоит писать оскорбления