# Как реализован вызов метода через метод?

Tags: php, ооп

иногда встречаю такой код

```
$a = new A;
$a->method1()->method2();
```

как реализовать method2 и что это по сути *замыкание* или *колбэк* ?

Comment: `return $this;`

Comment: Просто method1 возвращает сам объект, к которому точно так же можно применять методы этого класса. И это не является ни замыканием, ни колбеком

Comment: а можно пример кода

Comment: [Fluent Interface](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Structural/FluentInterface/README.html)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов нескольких функций класса разом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704204/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто метод method1 возвращает экземпляр объекта класса. Таким образом $a->method1() является тем же самым объектом A, с которыми совершили какие-то действия этом методе. Это не является ни колбеком, ни замыканием.

```
class A {

    public function method1() {
        // какой-то код
        return $this; // возвращает сам себя
    }

    public function method2() { 
        // какой-то код
        return $this;
    }
}
$a = new A();
$a->method1()->method2();
```

Такую структуру используют скорее для удобства. Если бы методы не возвращали объект, то конструкция выглядела бы

```
$a = new A();
$a->method1();
$a->method2();
```